# In one JSON object one field has same value but rest of fields has different values , need same value as common rest of values as list of items

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I am grouping the list of items by resource name, I am getting output like below i.e in every JSON object `resourceName` is the same, and other field values are different, but I need that resource name should come as common value and rest of the come as list of values.

```json
{"groupedResourceDtos": {
    "Resource PopCheck": {
        "9": [{
            "id": 9,
            "resourceName": "Resource PopCheck",
            "groupedMonths": {
                "id": 9,
                "monthName": "Aug",
                "noOfLicenses": 8
            }
        }],
        "10": [{
            "id": 10,
            "resourceName": "Resource PopCheck",
            "groupedMonths": {
                "id": 10,
                "monthName": "Sep",
                "noOfLicenses": 11
            }
        }],
        "11": [{
            "id": 11,
            "resourceName": "Resource PopCheck",
            "groupedMonths": {
                "id": 11,
                "monthName": "Oct",
                "noOfLicenses": 7
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

but I am expecting like

```json
{"groupedResourceDtos": {
    "resourceName":  "Resource PopCheck",
    "groupedMonths": [{
        "id": 9,
        "monthName": "Aug",
        "noOfLicenses": 8
    },{
        "id": 10,
        "monthName": "Sep",
        "noOfLicenses": 11
    },{
        "id": 11,
        "monthName": "Oct",
        "noOfLicenses": 7
    }]
}}
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and show some code, i.e. what did you try so far? Also note that json data doesn't help that much without seeing the objects it is mapped to and the code you want to use to generate the required output. Also please reformat your post to make it more readable (e.g. fix indentation) and explain more how the output you need should be constructed and from what input.

Comment: The expected JSON is invalid, please review and provide proper JSON example or better a POJO.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I provided proper JSON please check once , Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the DTO classes need to be defined for the mentioned JSON.
This can be done as follows (using Lombok annotations):

```java
@Data
static class Dto {
    private Map<String, Map<String, List<MyResource>>> groupedResourceDtos;
}

@Data
static class MyResource {
    int id;
    String resourceName;
    GroupedMonth groupedMonths;
}

@Data
static class GroupedMonth {
    int id;
    String monthName;
    int noOfLicenses;
}
```

Then the DTO for expected output should look like this:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Remap {
    private String resourceName;
    private List<GroupedMonth> groupedMonths;
}
```

Assuming that there is a valid instance of `Dto` class parsed from the input JSON using Jackson `ObjectMapper`, the remapped instance can be created using `Stream::flatMap` and `Stream::map` operations applied to the contents of the the maps:

```java
String json = "{...};" // large input JSON 

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Dto dto = mapper.readValue(json, Dto.class);

Remap remap = dto.groupedResourceDtos.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(e -> new Remap(
        e.getKey(), // resourceName
        (e.getValue().values()      // Collection<List<MyResource>>
            .stream()               // Stream<List<MyResource>>
            .flatMap(List::stream)  // Stream<MyResource>
            .map(MyResource::getGroupedMonths) // Stream<GroupedMonth>
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ) // List<GroupedMonth>
   ))
   .findFirst() // Optional<Remap>, dealing with only 1 value
   .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

Then `remap` value may be serialized to JSON:

```java
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(remap));
```

Output:

```
{
  "resourceName" : "Resource PopCheck",
  "groupedMonths" : [ {
    "id" : 9,
    "monthName" : "Aug",
    "noOfLicenses" : 8
  }, {
    "id" : 10,
    "monthName" : "Sep",
    "noOfLicenses" : 11
  }, {
    "id" : 11,
    "monthName" : "Oct",
    "noOfLicenses" : 7
  } ]
}
```